# What is the best way to inform a StackOverflow User of an error in an algorithm without proper reputation?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

All,

I'm a new user to both StackOverflow and this Meta Stack Overflow.

I recently found an error in an otherwise very helpful algorithm posted by User Tri Q. The algorithm is linked here:

[How can I find WPF controls by name or type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls/1501391#1501391)

My question for the board is: I only have 25 reputation points on StackOverflow. **How can I inform this insightful user that he made an error in the algorithm, and my intended fix?** Typically I'd add a comment to this post and recommend my fix, is it better to add an "answer" to the post with a reference to his post below?

I'm currently in the middle of determining a fix to the problem, but a summary of the problem is that that after the child is found in  `foundChild = FindChild(child, childName, childType);` it is possible for the `for` loop to continue iterating and overwrite the found child.

Comment: Your eventual answer isn't "above" if you're on the same level of votes or sorted by newest. Better to just link to their answer next time if you're referring to it instead of spatial relations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Best, but slower: find some other question to answer and getting upvoted so you can leave a comment.. you only need 25 more rep.

Okay, but you can do it right now: just post an answer of your own (and explain that you can't leave comments yet), with a corrected version of the algorithm. If you improve upon the other guy's answer, you'll get upvoted and then you can leave comments on other posts, huzzah!

Comment: Thanks... I ended up posting an answer of my own that hopefully improved upon the algorithm that he used. link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls/1759923#1759923 

I figure **bolding** the error is the best i can do until I can comment...

Comment: Reputation bootstrapping!